# Tool for finding ASP.NET tag errors?

Tags: asp.net, testing, automated-tests

is there a tool that will run through an ASP.NET site, and reports on any pages that error?

We're starting a new web app project at work, and I'm thinking over the things it would have been handy to have in the last. I'm looking to find those little mistakes that creep through the gaps with server tags - things like:

- Include path for a control is a victim of copy/paste
- A piece of logic is suffers from changes in the page lifecycle
- Refactor doesn't reach the .as[c|p]x page

I'm aware that some design patterns purport to solve some of these issues, but I'm being realistic about what I'm likely to encounter.

What am I looking for?

- I'd be fine to specify the list of
  URLs (~30 pages once the site's
  done).
- I'd also be fine with
  recording a sequence of clicking
  through all pages.
- Must be able to
  handle Forms auth
- Growl-style
  notification + command line execution
  would be great.

  - (Looking to include it as a post-build task)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You should check that VS is setup as XHTML compliant. This can be done from the ASPX view of the page. The non-compliant items will show in the warning or errors section.

Comment: It's a start. Don't HTML/CSS compliance errors require the page to be open to show in that section? (Editing Page A may break page B, which isn't open in a tab). It'll also still miss changes in the code-behind breaking the page, which is something I was hoping to cover.